# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'roles_name_unique'")

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, entrust

I'm new to the Laravel entrust package. I'm trying to run a database seeder migration but everytime I do so it brings the following error

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'roles_name_unique'")

Any help is appreciated

THIS IS THE DATABASESEEDER.PHP

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Permission;
use App\User;
use App\Role;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
        public function run()
        {
          DB::table('users')->delete();
          // Create Admin Role
          $role = [
              'name'=> 'admin',
              'display_name'=> 'Admin',
              'description'=>'Full Permission'  
        ];
        $role = Role::create($role);

        /* Sets role permissions for users
          Get all permissions and attach them to the role */
          $permission::Get();
          foreach($permissions as $key => $value){
              $role->attachPermission($value);
          }
          //create Admin user
          $user = [
              'name'=> 'Admin User',
              'email'=>'admin@test.com',
              'Password'=> Hash::make('newasd123')
          ];
          $user = User::create($user);
          // set user role
          $user->attachRole($role);
        }
    }
```

THIS IS THE ENTRUST TABLE SETUP

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class EntrustSetupTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        // Create table for storing roles
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Create table for associating roles to users (Many-to-Many)
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
        });

        // Create table for storing permissions
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Create table for associating permissions to roles (Many-to-Many)
        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);


        });

        DB::commit();
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('permission_role');
        Schema::drop('permissions');
        Schema::drop('role_user');
        Schema::drop('roles');
    }
}
```

I expect the seeder to migrate it to the users table but the error message just keeps popping up

Comment: How are you migrating, what command are you using? Looks like your `roles` table doesn't get truncated and thus a role `admin` already exists when you try to `$role = Role::create($role);`.

Comment: I was using a database seeder. I was finally able to resorve the issue. it was occurring since I hadn't published the vendor files for the entrust package. after running ```php artisan vendor:publish``` and re ran the migration the issue was resolved. initially, it couldn' t register the many to many relationship defined in the vendor package